# Getting 63252 for Project Euler 21. Why is this incorrect?

Tags: java

Project Euler question:

Let d(n) be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n).
If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, where a ≠ b, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.

For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.

Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.

My solution in Java:

```
public class problem21 {

private static int answer = 0;
public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int a = 1; a<10000; a++){
        int b = calculateSumOfDivisorsOf(a);
        if(calculateSumOfDivisorsOf(b) == a && b!=a){
            //amicable numbers
            //a is always amicable
            answer+=a;
            if(b<10000){
                //b is an amicable number under 10000
                answer+=b;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
}
public static int calculateSumOfDivisorsOf(double num){
    String divisors = "1";
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i< Math.sqrt(num); i++){
        if(num%i == 0){
            divisors+= " " + i;
            if(num/i != i){
                divisors += " " + num/i;
            }
        }
    }

    double[] divisorsArr = new double[divisors.split("\\s+").length];
    for(int i = 0; i< divisors.split("\\s+").length; i++)
        divisorsArr[i] = Double.parseDouble(divisors.split("\\s+")[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i < divisorsArr.length; i++)
        sum+= divisorsArr[i];

    return sum;
}
```

}

My(incorrect) answer:
63252

What is wrong with my code?
The correct answer is 31626

Comment: Fire up the a debugger and execute your code step-by-step.

Comment: Not sure if it is an issue here, but why introduce floating point numbers and strings to store integers?

Comment: Does the numeric relationship between your answer and the correct one suggest anything to you?  It does to me.

Comment: @CPerkins yes I know it is half of the answer I have, but I don't really see anything wrong with my code

Comment: What could cause a sum of a list of numbers to be double what it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to debug your code I found that you adding a,b (amicable numbers) twice. Check your code and output.

```
    for (int a = 1; a < 10000; a++) {
        int b = calculateSumOfDivisorsOf(a);
        if (calculateSumOfDivisorsOf(b) == a && b != a) {
            // amicable numbers
            // a is always amicable
            answer += a;
            System.out.println(a); //NOTE I AM PRINTING 'a'
            if (b < 10000) {
                // b is an amicable number under 10000
                answer += b;
                System.out.println(b); // //NOTE I AM PRINTING 'b'
            }
        }
  }
```

Output is:

```
220 
284
284
220
1184
1210
1210
1184
2620
2924
2924
2620
5020
5564
5564
5020
6232
6368
6368
6232
```

Now you can see that your are adding a,b twice. You didn't check whether a,b already add or not. Check below code.

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //List to add a,b
        for (int a = 1; a < 10000; a++) {
            int b = calculateSumOfDivisorsOf(a);
            if (calculateSumOfDivisorsOf(b) == a && b != a && !l.contains(a) && !l.contains(b)) { //Check whether list contain a,b
                // amicable numbers
                // a is always amicable
                answer += a;
                l.add(a); //add a to list
                if (b < 10000) {
                    // b is an amicable number under 10000
                    answer += b;
                    l.add(b); //add b to list
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
```